# Measure the size of data and instruction caches of an executable file

Tags: c++, c, executable, code-profiling

Is there a way to measure the following aspects when running an executable file (after compiling a c, c++ .... code)
-Size of the used data and instruction caches in (KB), or as a percentage
-Percentage of CPUs use

Comment: Executable files do not have data and instruction caches.

Comment: I meant when running the executable file

Comment: I imagine the caches will be full most of the time.

Comment: are you saying 100% of dcaches and icaches are used? is there a tool to see this ?

Comment: Unless something has flushed the caches recently they would normally be full unless the processor is enters a tight loop before the caches fill up.

Comment: You may be able to use [Cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html) on your program.

Answer (score 2):

Use following command to get the size of executable.

```
size <executable file name>
size a.out
```

[image]